# split and parse text with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some text like this:

> Mostly Cloudy. 27°C (Feels like 29). Humidity: 74% Winds: 15 km/hr W.

I want get just the "27°C" part of this text. How can I use jquery to access just this part of text?

Comment: You don't want the `°`? Just the `27` and the `C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only degree, so:

```
var str = "Mostly Cloudy. 27C (Feels like 29). Humidity: 74% Winds: 15 km/hr W";
var results = str.match(/\d+°C/g); //You get array with all degrees kind substrings
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you deliberately excluded the ° from the resulting string, then you could use:

```
var parts = "Mostly Cloudy. 27°C (Feels like 29). Humidity: 74% Winds: 15 km/hr W".match(/(\d+).(C)/),
    temp = parts[1] + parts[2];

console.log(temp);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xXjXE/).

Or, instead:

```
var parts = "Mostly Cloudy. 27°C (Feels like 29). Humidity: 74% Winds: 15 km/hr W".match(/(\d+).(C)/),
    temp = parts.slice(1).join('');

console.log(temp);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xXjXE/2/).

If, on the other hand, you want to retain the degree sign, then you could instead use:

```
var parts = "Mostly Cloudy. 27°C (Feels like 29). Humidity: 74% Winds: 15 km/hr W".match(/(\d+).(C)/),
    temp = parts[0];

console.log(temp);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xXjXE/1/).

References:

- [`array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`string.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: <br />Mostly Cloudy. 25&#176;C (Feels like 25). Humidity: 89% Winds: 15 km/hr WSW.<br />All times shown are local to Sārī, IRN.<br />

Comment: In which case I'd suggest using the second option, using slice: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xXjXE/3/).

Comment: my problem solved , and my new problem!!! i have multi line text i want get all degre from this tags how can do it
<div>
Today:T-storms.<img /> Lo: 23&#176;C. Hi: 29&#176;C.<br />
Tomorrow:T-storms.<img  /> Lo: 23&#176;C. Hi: 31&#176;C.<br />
Sunday:Showers / Clear.<img /> Lo: 22&#176;C. Hi: 34&#176;C.<br />
Monday:Fair.<img /> Lo: 22&#176;C. Hi: 34&#176;C.<br />
Tuesday:Clear.<img /> Lo: 22&#176;C. Hi: 35&#176;C<br />
</div>

Answer (score 1):

The below code will always display the temprature, irrespective of what the sentence is!!!

```
var str = "27°C (Feels like 29)"; 
arr = str.split('°'); 
words=arr[0].split(' ');
if(words.length>1)
    temp=words[words.length-1]+'°'+arr[1].substr(0,1); 
else
    temp=arr[0]+'°'+arr[1].substr(0,1); 
console.log(temp);
```